# What are the alternatives of using array as an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I used controls as an array here. What are some other options to pass the multiple property values as I used from 3 to 4 times in this array?

```js
import React from "react";
import BuildControl from "./BuildControl";
import styles from "./BuildControls.module.css";

const controls = [
    { label: "Salad", type: "salad" },
    { label: "Bacon", type: "bacon" },
    { label: "Cheese", type: "cheese" },
    { label: "Meat", type: "meat" },
];

const  buildControls =(props)=>(
    <div className={styles.BuildControls}>
        {controls.map(cntrl => (
            <BuildControl key={cntrl.label} type={cntrl.label}/>
        ))}
    </div>
);

export default buildControls;
```

Comment: I don't understand your question here. What is not working ?

Comment: i have edited my question .please react now

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem, it's just a style problem ?

You can do like this:

```js
const  buildControls =(props)=>(
 <div className={styles.BuildControls}>
    {controls.map(({ label }) => (
        <BuildControl key={label} type={label}/>
    ))}
 </div>
);
```

You unpack the object value directly in the function parameters